# xcode webview file open dialog not showing

Tags: xcode, web-applications, webview

I created an osx application in xcode that shows a webpage using a webview. But for some reason it is not showing the file open dialog in my webpages.

Safari and chrome seem to be fine so the page seems to be ok.

The only related setting for the webview i can find in xcode is "enable popups" but that's enabled. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanx
Wouter